If someone asks a question in Chinese, is the whole post "fair game" for feedback?
Continuing from Is it a problem if a learner asks/answers wholly in broken Chinese?
Question: If someone asks a question in Chinese, is the whole post "fair game" for feedback?
A hypothetical example:

我问我朋友这个问题，但是他们不知道。
问题：“还是”和“或者”有什么区别？

But answers comment on the grammar in the first part "我问我朋友这个问题，但是他们不知道", perhaps in addition to answering the main question.  [I think it needs a 了, i.e., 我问了...]

There's a related post at CodeReview.SE: Is it okay to give a review without actually answering some of the OP's requests?
And their on-topic page says:

...any aspect of the code posted is fair game for feedback and criticism.

But the situation is slightly different here, since the question encompasses the whole question.
(I haven't gone through each language site to see what they do.)

Maybe but that wouldn't be a proper, or at least clean, use of the site in my opinion.
Keep the answer about the question content. Answer it as if the question had been written correctly. 
If it has so many mistakes that it becomes incomprehensible, ask for clarification in the comments, and edit it accordingly helping the OP. 
In any case, after you edit the minor or major mistakes, don't forget to write what you changed and why in the edit summary. You can then post a brief comment under the question pointing to that edit summary.
One last thing: don't forget the rules for editing, the question cannot have its own meaning changed if there are answers already. In that case it's better to ask a new question and close the old one when necessary. 
Whenever it's unclear what to do, you can ask us moderators or the community on a case by case basis. 
Hope that helps. 
